# The role of Injectivity and Surjectivity on Equivalence Classes

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, problem-solving, equivalence-relations

This is a problem from *Proofs and Fundamentals* by Ethan D. Bloch that I’m struggling to solve:

> Let $f:A \to B$ a map. Define a relation $\sim$ on $A$ by letting $x \sim y$ iff and only if $f(x) = f(y)$, for all $x, y \in A$. What can be said about the equivalence classes of $\sim$, depending upon whether $f$ is injective but not surjective, surjective but not injective, neither or both?

So far, I realize that **if $f$ is injective, then all the equivalence classes of $\sim$ will have exactly one element** (and this comes also from the fact that $f$ is a map).

Although, I don’t think that the fact that $f$ is surjective or not will alter the equivalence classes. Can someone please help me understanding **what is the “relation” (if any) between surjectivity and equivalence classes?**

Thank you in advance for your attention!

Comment: For a surjective function, there will be an equivalence class for each value of the codomain, consisting of all elements of the domain that get mapped to it.

Comment: @JohnDouma note that $\sim$ is a relation on $A$, not on $B$

Comment: @Andrew There will still be an equivalence class for each element of $B$. The equivalence classes consist of elements of $A$.

Comment: @JohnDouma but that would be the equivalence classes of the relation $f$, not of $\sim$

Comment: @AirMike What are you talking about? The equivalence relation is on $A$ but for each element $b\in B$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. All elements of the equivalence class [$a$] get mapped to the same $b$ This construction can be made for every element of $B$. Likewise, every element of $A$ gets mapped to an element of $B$ because $f$ is a function so it is in an equivalence class corresponding to an element of $B$.

Comment: @JohnDouma sure! But that’s because you are considering the relation $f$ (because a map is a relation). The equivalence classes that I am talking about are on $A$ by the relation $\sim$

Comment: @AirMike "Define a relation ∼ on  by letting ∼ iff and only if ()=(),"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is surjective we see that for each $b\in B$ preimage $f^{-1}(b)$ is nonempty. Equivalence classes are like : $$[a] = \{x\in f^{-1}(b); b=f(a)\}$$

---

Since it is surjective we can only say that quotien set $A/_\sim$ and $B$ are set isomorphic (i.e. there is bijection between them).

Comment: Correct! But how does that influence in the equivalence classes? They will be non-empty either way

Comment: Well, it seem that it has no influence.

Comment: I agree, I also think it doesn't influence

Comment: I also thought of that! Thank you so much for the feedback!